# Chrome browser stucks on javascript execution

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mootools, lazy-loading, freeze

I using chrome version  26.0.1410.43 m. And I have problem with html code like this:

```
<div class="visos_prekes">
    <ul class="block-list list-1">
        <li class="simple">
            <div class="tac">
                <a href="link" title="STRING">
                    <img src="/img/blank.gif" style="background:url(link) center no-repeat;" alt="STRING" width="190" height="128" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <p>PRODUCT NAME</p>
            <div class="tt">
                STRING.<br /><br />
                STRING
                <strong>999999999</strong>
                <br />
                <div class="clear2"><strike class="mazkaina fr">999999999</strike></div>
            </div>
            <form method="post" action="link">
                <input name="klauskite" type="hidden" value="true" />
                <input name="klpatvirtinti" type="submit" style="cursor:pointer;border:none;margin-left:2px;margin-right:13px;width:80px;height:33px;display:inline-block;padding-bottom:20px;" value="Klauskite" title="Pateikite klausima apie šia preke" class="button-3 posrel block fl" />
                <a rel="nofollow" style="cursor:pointer;border:none;margin-right:4px;padding-bottom:10px;" title="Pridėti prekę i krepšeli" class="green-button-2 block posrel fr" onclick="checkCart()">
                    <span></span>
                    I krepšeli
                </a>            
            </form>
            <div class="clr">&nbsp;</div>
        </li>
        <li id="beforePagination"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I using lazy pagination to load a product in `<ul>` block, and when in `<ul>` block appears about 400+ elements of `<li>` with code like I copy before, I try to do that function in javascript with mootools:

```
$$('.visos_prekes').set('html', '<ul class="block-list list-1"><li id="beforePagination"></li></ul>');
```

But when I that function executing in Chrome, it freezes about 3sec. That code I tryed on IE8, Firefox and its working fine wihout any freezes. How should I handle this?

Comment: what is the .set you are using? the $$ is the same as using document.querySelectorAll, and it returns a NodeList, which doesn't have .set function, this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ktddr/1/ (i think) is what you mean, and it doesn't work for me in IE (nor does it freeze chrome...)

Comment: `$$ is the same as using document.querySelectorAll` -> no, it is not. if you don't know mootools, don't give out the wrong answers based upon speculation and what you know about web dev tools that support $$. it returns an Elements collection. mootools is also prototypical, all elements have `Element.prototype.set`

Answer (score 0):

$$ function in mootools return Elements instance - try to call the element you want and set to it the html - I guess you want this:

```
$$('.visos_prekes')[0].set('html', '<ul class="block-list list-1"><li id="beforePagination"></li></ul>');
```